# I have an error, and i am unsure why it is not working (threads)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to make a thread and have it run inside a function. For some reason it doesn't work. Here is my code. I have no idea what is wrong and what the errors mean. The errors it gives me are the following: no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list. The other error is: "std::thread::thread": none of the 3 overloads could convert all argument types.

```
void f1opp(int hit) {


thread tme((timer()));

getline(cin, choi);

if (choi == "punch")
{
    cout << "You try to punch him" << endl;
    ran = rand() % 3;

    if (ran == 1)
    {
        cout << "You hit him for 3 damage" << endl;
        i = 1 + 123456789;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You miss" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

tme.join();
}

// the timer program
void timer(int hit) 

{
    if (hit >= 3)
{

    for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        if (s == 0)
        {
            cout << "They were able to hit you" << endl;
            hit = hit + 1;
            break;
        }
        system("cls");
        s--;
        cout << "He attacks you in:" << s << endl;
        Sleep(1000);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `timer` takes one parameter. What argument do you want the thread to call it with?

Answer (score 0):

```
thread tme((timer()));
```

should be changed to below, assume you want to pass int 100 to timer function

```
thread tme(timer, 100);
```